# CPLEX limitations of binary variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to solve a mixed-integer linear program with about 36.000 binary variables, 164.000 continious variables and 3.420.000 constraints. Is there a way for me to know if it is solvable using CPLEX?

Many thanks

Comment: No. This is very large, so it may be very difficult. But without trying you never know. Also, if too difficult to find a proven optimal solution, Cplex may find a good solution relatively quickly. Furthermore: implementing the model and doing some experiments may give you ideas for improvements in the formulation of the model.

Comment: Okay many thanks. Is there somewhere I could find Cplex limitations?

Comment: There are no practical limits. You will run out of memory or patience before hitting any physical limits.

Comment: As Erwin says, it may be very difficult, but it is worth trying. I have successfully solved some problems with several hundreds of thousands of binary variables using CPLEX when we get lucky with the model, and CPLEX's heuristics work well. In other cases I have not solved problems with just a few thousand binary variables in several days. It depends a great deal on the specific structure and numerical characteristics of your model. If your model is hard, you may be able to use decomposition (e.g. column generation) or invent some hybrid scheme such as VLNS to get good answers faster.